# How to implicitly set parent/child member references in a data structure

Tags: c#, data-structures

I have a class `DataStructure` that holds instances of `DataProperty` in an organized hierarchy of sub-classes that all implement interface `ICategory`. When this `DataStructure` is initialized, all it's sub-categories and properties are initialized automatically as well so everything is ready for writing data to it.

```
public interface IDataStructureMember
{
    public ICategory Parent { get; set; }
}

public interface ICategory : IDataStructureMember
{
    public List<ICategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
    public List<IDataProperty> Properties { get; set; }
}

public interface IDataProperty : IDataStructureMember { }

public abstract class Category : IDataStructureMember
{
    public ICategory Parent { get; set; }
    public List<ICategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
    public List<IDataProperty> Properties { get; set; }
}

public class DataProperty<T> : IDataProperty
{
    public ICategory Parent { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

//This is just a small excerpt, the actual DataStructure is almost ten times as large in terms of members and sub-category levels
public class DataStructure : Category 
{
    public EnvironmentData Environment { get; init; } = new();
    public ModelData Model { get; init; } = new();

    public class EnvironmentData : Category
    {
        public LightData Light { get; init; } = new();
        public List<Force> Forces { get; init; } = new();

        public class LightData : Category
        {
            public LightPositionData LightPosition { get; init; } = new();
            public DataProperty<double> Intensity { get; init; } = new();

            public class LightPositionData : Category
            {
                public DataProperty<List<double>> OriginCoordsXYZ { get; init; } = new();
                public DataProperty<List<double>> TargetCoordsXYZ { get; init; } = new();
            }
        }
        public class Force : Category
        {
            public DataProperty<string> ForceName { get; init; } = new();
            public DataProperty<double> Magnitude { get; init; } = new();
        }
    }
    public class ModelData : Category
    {
        public DataProperty<string> ModelName { get; init; } = new();
        public DataProperty<string> ModelFilePath { get; init; } = new();

        public class ModelProperties : Category
        {
            public DataProperty<List<double>> BoundingBox { get; init; } = new();
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is, I need each `DataProperty` to hold reference to it's parent `ICategory`, and same for every sub-category (classes that implement `ICategory` and extend `Category`), but they also need to keep references to their sub-categories and properties. This is required for fast navigation through the `DataStructure` hierachy in order to search for a specific property or category, perform cloning operations, and so on. For example:

```
DataStructure newStructure = new();
List<IDataProperty> envProperties = newStructure.Environment.Light.Properties; //should return references to DataStructure.EnviromentData.LightData properties
ICategory p = newStructure.Model.ModelName.Parent; //should return reference to DataStructure.Model
```

Calling Reflection every time these operations are required would be highly inefficient, so I figured it would be more optimal to set these parent/child references during the initialization of `DataStructure`, or when new members are added to the lists (for example, to the `List<Force>` in this example - that part I know how to do, but it's not a part of this code example to keep things simple).

What I don't know how to do, is how to set the `Parent`, `SubCategories` and `Properties` references in the least painful way. Ideally I would request these references in the constructor of `DataProperty` or `Category` - then I could simply add `this` to every `new()` statement, for example: `public DataProperty<double> Intensity { get; init; } = new(this)`. Unfortunately this is not allowed.

I know I could add explicit constructors to every class that extends `Category`, and set these references there, but that would require me to explicitly type out all the properties again. The `DataStructure` I quoted above is just a small fraction of the real structure I have in my code, so **having to type out any property or category name twice for any reason whatsoever would be a maintenance nightmare** - this I want to avoid at all costs.

So, is there any way to set these parent/child references implicitly during `DataStructure` initialization? I am not against using Reflection in this stage, since it would be done once, but I am not really sure how to do that, and perhaps there is another way?

Comment: "better" is in the eye of the beholder. Provide an objective measurement that can help determine whether one technique is "better" than another, otherwise answers will end up with arguments (sorry, discussions) in the comments, something Stack Overflow wishes to avoid.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you for the correction. Reflection is sub-optimal here because of performance concerns, and also because it seems to be a dirty fix for something that should be simple with correct code writing practices. However, the only alternative I know is adding these properties and categories into lists manually (like in Jonas answer), which is tedious, as it requires to type out every element twice (once to declare it, and another to add it to a list). I am searching for a solution that has neither of these drawbacks.